# .net core 2.2 (API) + react(ui) Docker file

Tags: .net, reactjs, docker

I am completely new to docker and trying to figure out how to use docker in a case where I have a solution with 7 projects, in my case its API.
And for UI I use reactJS.

I tried this one Dockerfile. Front is running on port 3000 and it working, but I don't have connect to API inside container.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY /admin.api/DeployOutput/ ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Admin.Api.dll"]

FROM node:12 as react-build
WORKDIR /app
COPY /admin.ui/ ./

RUN npm install
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

In package.json I enter URL to connect to API

```
  "proxy": "https://localhost:5001",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
```

if I run it locally (not using Docker) - the project works

API is running on port 5000 and 5001.

I need to write Dockerfile, which will create image with UI+API

Comment: I think you are looking for `docker-compose` which can run multi-applications at once.

Comment: I now about docker-compose.yml, but i need put this project(API + UI) in one Dockerfile

Comment: If you want to bundle the react app + the API-project in the same docker file - your dockerfile must be above both folders (e.g. context)

Comment: I would suggest you to run your API in one docker container and your frontend in a separate docker container, but it depends on if your frontend is hard coupled with the backend (most likley not). But for them to communicate with each other, you also need a docker network and you can't reference `localhost` inside the container to reach another container. Also, you need to map what ports to your container when you start it, `localhost` on your host machine is not the same as `localhost` inside the container. But have a look at `docker-compose` for multi containers.

Comment: My docker file above both folders

Comment: Well, then you could package your frontend and api in the same docker container (not recommended). This is also a lot harder to do.

Comment: Here is an example to package your API https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/ - note there is a build step and also a runtime step (runtime is a more slim version and you don't need the SDK to run it, only to build it)
For the frontend container, I would suggest you to do your `npm` stuff in 2 steps aswell, one build container based from `node:<version>` and then host the compiled JS files on a webserver as runtime, e.g `nginx:stable`.

Comment: Let me know if you want me to post a simular solution.

Comment: it would be cool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So my recommended approach is to use two separate containers, one for the API and another for the frontend.

`#1 API`

```sh
# Step 1 - build
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /build

COPY . . # copy everything from where the dockerfile is, to current workdir inside the container (sloppy but it works)
RUN dotnet publish -o out # compile the dll's and put them in an "out" directory

# Step 2 - runtime (compiled dll:s)
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /build/out . # copy your compiled dll's from your BUILD CONTAINER and place them inside your runtime container

EXPOSE 5000/tcp # this is only to document what port is in use
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "API.dll", "--urls", "http://*:5000"] # the name of your DLL to run
```

One thing that I think is useful for "debugging" the builds in dockerfiles is to add `RUN ls -al` to output the current directory, so you can see where you're at what what files are produced. Feel free to add them.

`#2 Frontend - angular example, but is probably very simular to react`

```sh
# build
FROM node:10.9.0-alpine as node
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

# npm install
RUN npm i -g @angular/cli@8.3.2
RUN npm install
RUN ng build --prod

# runtime
FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine
COPY --from=node /app/out /usr/share/nginx/html

# RUN rm -r /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf # replace with your own server config if you like
COPY --from=node /app/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

Ok, so let's say you have now built your docker containers, frontend and API. Only to start a single container, use `docker run <image name>` - but this has not mapped any ports to your `host machine`. To do this, add arguments for port mapping - something like this `docker run -p 3999:5000 <image name>`. To verify it's running, open a browser and navigate to `localhost:3999/your/api/endpoint`.

The first argument `-p 3999:5000` maps your host machines port `:3999` to the isolated containers port `:5000`, you can swap this at will.

See `docker --help` for more options.

Another usefull tip is to enter a command shell from your host machine to the running container, to do this, do `docker exec -it <container_id> bash` or `docker exec -it <container_id> sh`. To list running containers, do `docker ps` or `docker ps -a`.

Feel free to ask questions if you want me to update this post. Cheers!